# Provider gets out of scope while dragging Widget in ReorderableListView and throws Error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The app I am trying to make includes a `ReorderableListView`. The List comprises of items that use a `Consumer` widget and the `ChangeNotifierProvider` for that widget is placed directly below the Scaffold in a `MultiProvider`.

The List Items itself are designed with Options. For example, the user can choose to make the list item blue,red or green. So when I'm dragging and reordering the list item, the item should move with the decoration specified by the User.

**Here's images to help with visualizing the usecase:**
[image: Each row in the grid is a List item of ReorderableListView]
[image: The Error]

---

However, I am getting the following error when I try to reorder an item:

*Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Selector<TopsterBoxesController, TopsterBoxData> Widget*

*This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.*

So basically, what I am understanding is, when I reorder List items, the draggable when dragged is going out of scope and not able to find my provider.
I tried to place the `ChangeNotifierProvider` right above my `MaterialApp` widget too, but that also yields the same error.

When the reorder is complete, there is no problem. My ListItem automatically moves and settles with the appropriate design, so it is able to find the Provider again.

**Would greatly appreciate if anybody knows of a workaround. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your list item with a
`InheritedProvider<T>.value(value: T,child: YourListItem())`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).